# rvm ruby installation not working for 2.2

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm getting an error in OSX with:

`rvm install 2.2`

I was able to install Ruby 2.5 just fine. But with 2.2 I get:

```
//  rvm install "ruby-2.2.10" --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
ruby-2.2.10 - #removing src/ruby-2.2.10..
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system..........
Installing required packages: openssl.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.10 - #downloading ruby-2.2.10, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.2.10 - #extracting ruby-2.2.10 to /Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.10.....
ruby-2.2.10 - #applying patch /Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.10/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch.
ruby-2.2.10 - #configuring.....................................................-
ruby-2.2.10 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.2.10 - #compiling....
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/log/1611519469_ruby-2.2.10/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

When I open the log file it's meaningless to me. It begins:

```
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.10
GEM_HOME=/Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/bin:/Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8@global/bin:/Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/bin:/Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8:/Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8@global
command(2): __rvm_make -j4
++ make -j4
```

Then a bunch more stuff, and it ends:

```
encoding.c:825:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_str_change_terminator_length' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        rb_str_change_terminator_length(obj, oldtermlen, termlen);
        ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [encoding.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
++ return 2
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Thanks, the info in that link fixed it! Now it's still not installing due to a different error message. ```Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.10@global GEM_PATH= /Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/bin/ruby -d /Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.9/setup.rb --no-document',
please read /Users/jeffslutzky/.rvm/log/1611545952_ruby-2.2.10/rubygems.install.log```

Comment: If I was you, I'd create a new question with all the relevant info for this new error, to have a better reception from the SO community. Cheers